# Perl dies on big XML file, using STDIN

Tags: xml, macos, perl, debugging, unix

I get this error when I run a perl script:

```
unclosed token at line 1, column 0, byte 0 at /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/XML/Parser.pm line 187.

at mysscript.pl line 8.
```

Heres line 8 at `mysscript.pl`

```
$twig->parse( \*STDIN);
```

I tried some other variations like:

```
$twig->parse(\*STDIN);
$twig->parse(*STDIN);
```

But they didn't work, I know that it also says that there is something wrong with my perl system files but i doubt that, i found someone that had the same problem and he had to fix his code instead.

Answer (score 1):

That's an XML error, not a Perl error. It does suggest you've got broken XML. 
You can trap it by `eval` in the parse.

But actually - thinking about it - the problem is probably that you're only reading the first line of `STDIN` with your `parse`. 
Try adding:

```
{ 
    local $/;
    $twig -> parse ( <STDIN> );
}
```

However, for large XML files, I quite like `XML::Twig`, because it has a `purge` method, which lets you throw away XML you've already processed. One of the downsides of XML is that it's memory footprint is approx 10x the raw file size. So it's possible you're running out of memory if your file is particularly huge.

Comment: Check my edit - I think it's because you're only reading the first line of the XML. How big is your file anyway?

Comment: I don't think that's the problem here, STDIN should be parsed properly with this syntax

Comment: Your fix is correct, as it will read the whole file and pass the XML data to `parse`. However the problem isn't that only the first line is being read, as *nothing* is being read in the original question. A file handle is being passed when an XML data string is expected. The best way to get `XML::Twig` to parse a file is to pass the *file name* to `parsefile`. There is no method that accepts a file handle.

Comment: @mirod: No. No, it shouldn't. The syntax is completely wrong in the OP's code. But Sobrique's fix is correct, albeit a non-optimal solution for the wrong reason.

Comment: Yes, I was going off in the wrong direction before the problem hit me. I think this is the only way to run `STDIN` through XML::Twig - but picking it up through parsefile is probably more appropriate.

Comment: @mirod: I apologise and have been corrected: the `parse` method is fine with a (reference to) a file handle, so `$twig->parse(\*STDIN)` should be fine.

Comment: If that's the case, then my suggestion probably shouldn't make any difference, and the problem is (probably) broken XML all along (probably blank first line or similar).

Answer (score 0):

`$twig->parse( \*STDIN)` is the proper syntax, so that's not what causing the error.

So it looks like either there is a problem with your XML or there is a bug somewhere. Did you try checking your XML (with `xmlwf` or `xmllint` or a similar tool)? If it parses, then what is the encoding of the XML? If it's UTF-16 then that might be the problem, `libexpat` (on which XML::Twig is based) seems to have trouble with this encoding.

Comment: `$twig->parse(*STDIN)` is *wrong*. The `parse` method expects a string containing a valid XML document, not a file handle. In general, a *file handle* can be passed as a parameter by using either `*STDIN` or `\*STDIN`, but there are some cases that will accept only one or the other, and the latter is the most common.

Comment: Oops! The SO gremlins ate my backslash (actually, I typed it but it didn't show up in the post). I fixed it.

Comment: I apologise and have been corrected: the `parse` method is fine with a (reference to) a file handle.

Answer (score 0):

The `XML::Twig` module has only two basic ways of reading the XML to be parsed:

- `parse`, which expects a *string* containing the XML data as a parameter
- `parsefile`, which expects a *string* that specifies the name (and path) of an XML file to be read

The is no option to pass an open file handle, and if you write `$twig->parse(\*STDIN)` or `$twig->parse(*STDIN)` then you will be passing (something like) the strings `GLOB(0x44b574)` and `*main::STDIN` respectively, which is clearly not valid XML.

I presume you can work out from there what your call should look like. If you are passing the file name as a parameter on the command line then the simplest solution is to write

```
$twig->parsefile(shift)
```

but without more information I can't help you any further.

Comment: Actually, [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/) _does_ support supplying a file handle to the `parse` method. Here is the relevant excerpt from the perldoc: "The $source parameter should either be a string containing the whole XML document, or it should be an open IO::Handle (aka a filehandle)."

Comment: @SamChoukri: Thank you for correcting me. I guess I overlooked that because there is no *example* of passing a file handle in the documentation.